# Проблема сети на виртуалке Lxc Debian8

Tags: debian, ssh, виртуализация

Я установил виртуалку ***lxc***. Она работает, я могу к ней подключится с host машины. Я прописал для нее статический ip и хотел настроить ssh. Но когда я запускаю команду ...

```
apt-get update
```

говорит, что не может подключится к сети. Как можно проверить сеть и в чем может быть проблема?

Дополнительно:

- да, команду выполняю в контейнере

Вывод команды `ip a` :

> 1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
>   group default  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo    valid_lft forever preferred_lft
>   forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host     valid_lft forever preferred_lft
>   forever 11: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc
>   pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether
>   00:50:56:00:9c:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 213.239.197.122/8 brd
>   213.255.255.255 scope global eth1    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe00:9c81/64 scope link     valid_lft
>   forever preferred_lft forever

Вывод команды `ip r` :

> default via 213.239.197.97 dev eth1 
>   213.0.0.0/8 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 213.239.197.122

Вывод команды `cat /etc/resolv.conf` :

> domain your-server.de search your-server.de nameserver 213.133.98.98
>   nameserver 213.133.99.99 nameserver 213.133.100.100

Comment: уточните: команду выполняете внутри контейнера? тогда приведите (в вопросе) и вывод `ip a; ip r; cat /etc/resolv.conf`, выполненной тоже внутри контейнера.

Comment: добавил все в тело вопроса